# Could not get unknown property 'uploadArchives' for task set of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer

Tags: android

how to repair this problem,...

A problem occurred configuring project ':DragRecylerView'.

> Could not get unknown property 'uploadArchives' for task set of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.

```
dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have comptiable versions of gradle and AGP

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle

check gradle version in gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties